# How to model this simple logic circuit using dynamical systems techniques.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would like to mathematically model this simple logic circuit:

[image: OR gate with feedback]

In addition, the input to input1 of this gate would also be some function that looked something like this:

[image: some input voltage]

Given a continuous function $f(x1,x2)$ that represents OR1, and a continuous function $g(x)$ that represents input into input1, how could dynamical system techniques be used to model this as a continuous non-linear system?  Having no training in dynamical systems I'm not sure where to start.  What would be a good textbook or tutorial that could help me start making progress with this?

Comment: Are you using the "or" gate symbol to represent a continuous function or are you assuming there is a continuous function that represents the "or" gate?

Comment: Is the loop to be interpreted as `in2[k]=out[k-1]`, that is `out[k] = in1[k] or out[k-1]`? And you are looking for a continuous version of this?

Comment: @JohnDouma - this is assuming $f(x1,x2)$ is a continuous function that represents the 'or' gate.

Comment: @Lutlz - loop is to be interpreted as $out[k] = in1[k] or out[k-1]$ and yes...looking for a continuous version.  Please assume $f(x1,x2)$ is a continuous function that represents the OR function.

Comment: There is no continuous function that models an or gate. Think about bootstrapping the system. The output will be $0$ and as soon as $g\gt 0$, the gate will abruptly switch to $1$.

Comment: [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2764636/) is a paper that may have what you want. The scenario appears to be more complicated than what you describe because the feedback loop is disabled during bootstrapping.

Comment: @JohnDouma - there are probably multiple ways of modeling an OR gate with continuous functions, but that isn't the jist of my question here.  We could instead replace OR with just addition (ie $f(x1,x2) = x1+x2$) and my question would still hold - how could dynamical systems be used to model this corresponding circuit.  I guess this is the context in which I hope to find a good textbook or tutorial as a guide.